# How to put a JFileChooser on top of a Stage

Tags: java, javafx, jfilechooser

I have a JFileChooser that I want to appear on top of a Stage (`parentStage` below). How can I go about doing that?

I would like the JFileChooser to have the same behavior as a `Stage` would have when `stage.initOwner(initOwner);` is set.

```
@Autowired
MyStagesClass myStagesClass;

public JFileChooser jFileChooser() throws Exception {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

    chooser.updateUI(); // Create UI objects
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    refreshUI(chooser, false);

    Stage parentStage = myStagesClass.getStage();

    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    return chooser;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use the showOpenDialog method of JFileChooser.  JFileChooser is actually a JComponent, so place it in a [SwingNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html), then place that SwingNode in a DialogPane (or in Group or BorderPane inside a Scene, if using an old version of JavaFX).

Comment: I strongly recommend not mixing Swing windows and FX windows in the same application. Either do as @VGR suggests and wrap the `JFileChooser` in a `SwingNode` in a `Stage`, or just use `javafx.stage.FileChooser`.

Comment: @James_D Agreed.  I think perhaps JFileChooser is being used because JavaFX's choosers have no equivalent to `setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES)`.

Comment: Ummm... Are you sure you want to do this? `JFileChooser` is known to be absolute crap, both in functionality and looks. the `javafx.stage.FileChooser` is much better. You should be using that instead.